# check answer of multi select question through checkbox to show correct answer angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I want to check if the answer is right and show correct word or if wrong show wrong by check if the checked boxes is_answer = 1 or not

I return the answers inside an array `vm.quiz_multi_answer = [];
  vm.quiz_multi_answer.push();`
I want to loop through choices to compare the selected answer with is_answer

```
vm.quiz_multi_data = [
    {
      question: "What does HTML stand for?",
      choices: [
        {
          id: "0",
          choice: "HyperText Markup Language",
          is_answer: "1"
        },
        {
          id: "1",
          choice: "HyperText Markup Language",
          is_answer: "1"
        },
        {
          id: "2",
          choice: "HyperText Markup Language",
          is_answer: "0"
        },
        {
          id: "3",
          choice: "HyperText Markup Language",
          is_answer: "0"
        }
      ]
    }
  ];
```

Comment: You need to explain your problem better and add html code too

Answer (score 0):

you can loop through this like

```
for(let i =0  ;i < quiz_multi_data.length ; i ++ ){
 if(quiz_multi_data[i].question/_id == "any_question_veriable"){
    for(let j =0 ; j < quiz_multi_data[i].choices[j].length ; j++ ){
           if( quiz_multi_data[i].choices[j]._id == id){
              //perform some logic 
            }
    }
}
```